# Autocomplete not using correct reference call

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, autocomplete

I have a function that creates my autocompletes.  Under normal circumstances it works just fine.  An example of the function call is:

```
getList('employee', { type: 'auto', id: 'txtMgrID', callback: function (id) { $('#hidMgrID').val(id); } });
```

This function call works just fine for me - what it does is create an autocomplete to the text input element txtMgrID, using an employee list.  The 'callback' sets the select function on the autocomplete - and in this example, sets a hidden input element 'hidMgrID' with the autocomplete id value.  Again - normally works just fine ( have this running in multiple places on my site. )

The issue i'm coming across is when I'm building this in a loop.  I have a dialog window that will have multiple employee autocompletes.  So I'm building the section of the dialog with a loop ( so it creates txtMgr0 - txtMgr4, along with hidMgrID0 - hidMgrID4 ).  And the dialog can be creating any number of those ( depending on how many direct employees a given manager has ), which is why I'm using a loop to do this.

After the dialog is open, I'm using another for loop to make the autocomplete creation call.  My exact code is:

```
for (x = 0; x < mgrcnt; x++) { 
    getList('employee', { type: 'auto', id: 'txtMgr' + x, callback: function (id) { $('#hidMgrID'+x).val(id); } }); 
}
```

Now, the issue I have is that ALL the autocomplete text boxes update the LAST hidID...  it's as if, in my example, the $('#hidMgrID'+x) evaluates to $('#hidMgrID4') for every getList call in the loop.  What's odd is if I put an alert call both before the get list call ( as part of the loop ), and also in the callback function reference ( before the jquery .val reference ) and as the dialog loads, it will give me #hidMgrID0 then 1, then 2, etc through all of them, and then when I enter a manager in the text element, it alerts #hidMgrID4 for ALL of them.

I'm not understanding why this is happening... and any help to get this figured out would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue: You are creating a function and storing it into callback property, but  the x variable is not evaluated right away. So when your function executes and x is evaluated, the x variable is mgrcnt, as the for has already ended.

A possible solution is using this idea:

What you are doing:

```
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    arr[i] =function(){
        console.log(3+i);
    }
}
console.log(i); // 10
arr[0](); // 13
arr[1](); // 13
```

What you should do:

```
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    (function(){
    var x=i;
        arr[x] =function(){
            console.log(3+x);
        }
    }())
}
console.log(i); // 10
arr[0](); // 3
arr[1](); // 4
```

Comment: No - this didn't work right... what I ended up having to do is make a function that returns the function I need...  `function makeCallback(i) { return function(id) { $('#hidMgr'+i).val(id); } }`  then referenced my callback to use makeCallback!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with my own answer after more research - basically I had to make an external function that returned the function that I needed:

```
function makeCallback(i) { 
    return function(id) { $('#hidMgr'+i).val(id); } 
}
```

then I was able to use it in my for loop:

```
for (x = 0; x < mgrcnt; x++) { 
    getList('employee', { type: 'auto', id: 'txtMgr' + x, callback: makeCallback(x) }); 
}
```

That solved my problem.